# Fact table - select distinct?

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, datamart

in my storage data model I got the following relations:

root_tbl -- 1:n -- entry_tbl -- n:1 -- action_tbl

There are a few more tables but this covers the basics.
Alright, so basically one ID from the root table has several datasets in the entry table.

Example data:

```
root_tbl:

ID_root ; Country ; FK_User ; FK_Product
      1 ;      UK ;      23 ;      31
      2 ;      NL ;      42 ;      01


entry_tbl:

ID_entry ; FK_root ; FK_Action ; Duration
       1 ;       1 ;        42 ; 200ms
       2 ;       1 ;        10 ; 94ms
       3 ;       1 ;         9 ; 300ms
       4 ;       2 ;        10 ; 322ms
       5 ;       2 ;        30 ; 100ms
```

So far so good ... with this data model it is pretty easy to answer things like how many records have "UK" as country with action "10" and so on.
Now I would like to put this data into a fact table but my problem are the relations of these three tables. For example would I use the records of entry_tbl as fact than I would have to do a select distinct on ID everytime I count country, user or product.

The fact table would look more or less like this (just imagine the strings as foreign keys ):

```
fact_tbl:

ID ; FK_Action ; Duration ; Country ; User ; Product
1  ;        42 ;    200ms ;      UK ;   23 ;      31
1  ;        10 ;     94ms ;      UK ;   23 ;      31
1  ;         9 ;    300ms ;      UK ;   23 ;      31
2  ;        10 ;    322ms ;      NL ;   42 ;      01
2  ;        30 ;    100ms ;      NL ;   42 ;      01
```

This means I would have a lot of redundant data.

Are there any way around these solution? The fact table would contain ~ 300 - 500m rows.

I hope you got my point. If anything is not clear feel free to ask

regards
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's usual to perform an aggregation on a fact table, in which case a distinct would be moot.

Here you need to use count(distinct) to count the number of ID's, but that is what a data warehouse is for. Similarly you might have to run a Sum(duration), or a count(distinct user), or a count(distinct product).

I don't think you have a design problem, you just have to ensure that you have enough available memory for your group by operations to run as far as possible without disk-based sorting. Monitor large queries through V$SQL_WORKAREA_ACTIVE, monitor the SGA and PGA cache advisors, and adjust the memory allocation if required.

Comment: I specified my question ... I hope this gives a better overview!

Comment: Alright, so basically what you are saying is that a denormalized fact table is common right?

Comment: I wouldn't describe it like that -- the fact table is a set of metrics (the facts) with associated classification (the dimensions). What you have there looks like a "degenerate dimension" if there's no separate dimension table for it, but counting metrics in a star schema are almost always going to require a distinct unless you're counting the number of facts themselves. To that in your model you'd have to denormalise it to be a single row per id, hence one column to hold duration for each possible action. That would be more of a datamart approach -- equally valid but not as extensible.

Comment: Well OK, I mean my fact_tbl from above will ofc contain a set of metrics, I just forgot to add them. But how is it possible to denormalize my example to a single row per ID ... one root_id has several Actions thats why I came up with that fact table.

Comment: It's only possible if you lose other dimensions by pivoting them or by aggregating to a higher level of atomicity.